Editing fstab to auto mount external exFAT HDDs at boot as a certain user
Fresh Ubuntu Server 24.04 LTS install with Gnome Desktop.
I have recently had issues after editing the mounting options via the "Disks" app. I decided a fresh install was the best fix. Now that I am back up and running, I want to make sure I set this up right the first time to avoid further issues.
The "disks" app made the proper changes and the drives did auto mount but they did so under root, which locked me out of making changes to the drives.
The 3 External HDDs I am trying to mount, are all formatted as exFAT, which I now understand does not support linux permissions:

SeaGate Barracuda Green 4TB x2
WesternDigital Black 2TB

When I made the changes rom the GUI, I was locked out of making changes to the drive or its contents as it made the changes under root, and although exFAT does not support the linux permissions, some of the permissions settings seem to be what broke everything the 1st time.
I am thinking that if I update my fstab with the correct mounting location and correct user that things should work as intended, even though the permissions settings are not technically supported.
Right now, I have to manually enter my password for each drive to mount, every time I reboot or unplug/unmount the drives, but they have the correct permissions when I do it this way.
How can I edit my fstab file to auto-mount the drives, but have the same settings that are used when I manually connect/mount the drives and enter my password? Right now, only the internal drive shows in the fstab file:
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/etc$ cat fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d39144ff-ae2d-407b-8fef-16482c35618c / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/BFAC-4024 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
jellyadmin@jellyfin-drake:/etc$ 


While exFAT better than FAT32, still not recommended as no journal. Some discussion of mounts here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482613 & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2479368&p=14113300#post14113300 Disks typically terrible for setting fstab entries, its defaults do not change for different types.  Also external drives need extra parameters like nofail, and x-systemd.device-timeout. Or: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fstab#Automount_with_systemd See also: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions
